# Decomposing MSE: Variance bias, or variance, bias AND noise?

Tags: error

First, it's known that MSE can be decomposed into variance and bias^2 of the estimator:

[image]

But on many sources a 3rd term called "irreducible error" should also be a part of the decomposition, which is supposed to describe the noise in the population model/ true relationship.

For [example](http://scott.fortmann-roe.com/docs/BiasVariance.html):

$Err(x) = \left(E[\hat{f}(x)]-f(x)\right)^2 + E\left[\left(\hat{f}(x)-E[\hat{f}(x)]\right)^2\right] +\sigma_e^2$

However, the first proof says that the MSE is described completely by the variance and bias. How do I make sense of this seeming contradiction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first case describes, say, the MSE of the OLS estimator $\hat\beta$ relative to the true value $\beta$ while the second describes the MSE of a prediction $\hat y_i=x_i\hat\beta$ made using the OLSE relative to the true $y_i$.

Comment: I was also able to find a source that says: $MSE[ˆ g(t)] = [E(ˆ g(t)−g(t))]^2 + V ar(ˆ g(t))$. Derived from $MSE[ˆ g(t)] = E[(ˆ g(t)−g(t))^2]$. Nowhere is it stated that the noise is 0. Is this a mistake?

Comment: That is tough to say without knowing what $g$ precisely is. Can you provide a reference?

Comment: unfortunately it's from a private course materials. But there really isn't anything more to it. g(t) is the fit and ^g(t) is its estimate.

Comment: Maybe it was tacitly ignored as we cannot do anything about the irreducible part anyhow.